# how to get first table row "<td></td>" text which are visible using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have a table

```
<table id="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Course</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr style="display:none">
        <td>jones</td>
         <td>.net</td>
   </tr>
  <tr style="display:none">
        <td>James</td>
         <td>SAP</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>Charles</td>
        <td>Java</td>  
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get text of first row  first td text which are visible using jquery, by
above table, I want result as "Charles".

How can get it. I have tried like

```
$("#table").closest('tbody').children('tr:first').find('td:first').text()
```

but not getting result.how can I?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `:visible` selector to get the visible rows,

```
$("#table tbody tr:visible:first td:first").text()
```

Comment: if we change the order to `$("#table tbody tr:first:visible").text();` then return nothing, will you please explain this?

Comment: @diEcho your selector will select the first row then it will filter out visible rows from that selected row.. Does it make sense..? :) :D

Comment: But there cant be row inside row in a valid html, doesnt jquery engine choose complete phrase , *first tr which is visible*

Comment: @diEcho That's why i am saying the selector that you have framed syntatically correct but semantically wrong.. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the visible one use the according :visible selector that jquery ships:

```
$('#table > tbody > tr:visible:first > td:first').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Worked for Me.

```
$('#table> tbody > tr:visible').first().find('td').first().text();
```